# Translations for graphs of $f(-x)$

Tags: functions

I was in class yesterday and I learned that $ f(x\pm a) $ will translate the graph horizontally. However, this doesn't work when we are dealing with $f(-x\pm a)$, I think it does the opposite of what $ f(x\pm a) $ would do. Why is this?

Comment: Hint : $f(-x-a)=f(-(x+a))$ and $f(-x+a)=f(-(x-a))$

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y = f(-x)$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $y = f(x)$ in the $y$ axis. And the graph of $y = f(-x+a), a > 0$, is obtained by shifting the graph of $y = f(-x)$ to the left $a$ units.

Answer (score 0):

Let y=-x . f(y+/-a) translates the corresponding graph precisely the same as for x (same function, same translation). But substituting back gives f(-x-/+a) which is a flip around the vertical axis.